# Use Bootstrap tooltips only if touch events are supported?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, touch, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using [Bootstrap tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) on my site:

```
$('body').tooltip({
  selector: '.help, .searchicons li, .user-prefs, .colour'
});
```

The only problem is that they don't work brilliantly on touch devices, when they are attached to elements that also have specific touch events attached.

Is there a way that I can disable them on touch elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect for touch capability and then only create the tooltip if touch is not enabled.

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

if (!is_touch_device) {
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: '.help, .searchicons li, .user-prefs, .colour'
    });
}
```